# Asp.Net Pass parameters to a stored procedure MODEL in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Im working with ASP.NET MVC and I have a model of a Stored Procedure that I created using EF Designer from my exisisting Database. Here I put my code:

```
public class SpGetClientPhonesController : ApiController
{
   ShopEntities2 db = new ShopEntities2();
    public string Get()
    {
        var json = "";

        spGetRegister_Result objmodel = new spGetRegister_Result( *HERE I SHOULD SPECIFY THE SP INPUT PARAMETERS*);


    }
}
```

I want to use this model to retrieve the data that the store procedure returns but I need to specify the input parameters first that this Store Procedure needs. How can I do that??

Answer (score 1):

If your model has been generated from the database and you have your stored proc referenced in it.

Then the way you would call the stored proc with Entity Framework would be as follows:

```
using(var db = new ShopEntities2())
{
  int id = 1234;
  var result = db.spGetRegister(id); //You should have intellisense here for your parameter(s) so `id` may not exactly correct but you get the idea. 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was digging and asking a little bit more and I was able to solve this problem. When Stored Procedures are mapped into Models using Entity Framework, you have to work with 2 concepts. Using my prevoius example with spGetRegister, when I created my model I had spGetRegister and spGetRegister_Result. 
The spGetRegister_Result is the one who handles what the Stored Procedure returns and spGetRegister is what I have to call with its input parameters. Here is the example:

```
ObjectResult<spGetRegister_Result> newRecord = new spGetRegister_Result;
newRecord = db.spGetRegister( IdClient:9587, IdSite:94);
```

From here you have the resulting row(s) of the Stored Procedure on the variable `newRecord` and you can do whatever you want with it.